# Find all real solutions: $36x^3 + 6x^2 = 9x$

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, quadratics

I am having trouble finding all the real solutions to this problem. I do not undertand how to solve it, and I have a test on Polynomials tomorrow. The problem is "Find all real solutions using your calculator. Round to the nearest hundredth: $36x^3 + 6x^2 = 9x$"

Comment: Sorry, but what is round to the nearest hundredth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can factor the equation as follows.
$$36x^{3} + 6x^{2} - 9x = 0$$
$$3x\left(12x^{2} + 2x - 3\right) = 0.$$

From this, you know that one solution is $\boxed{x = 0}.$ We must now find the solutions to $12x^{2} + 2x - 3 = 0.$ As this is not factorable, we can use the quadratic formula to find the others. We do this as follows.
$$x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 144}}{24}$$
$$= \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{148}}{24}$$
$$= \frac{-2 \pm 2\sqrt{37}}{24}$$
$$= \boxed{-\frac{1}{12} \pm \frac{\sqrt{37}}{12}}.$$

I leave you to find the decimal approximations.

Comment: How come you didn't count the coefficient, or the 2 in front of the radical sign, in the final solution?

Comment: Notice that I simplified the fraction by dividing $2$ on both fractions in the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite as $$36x^3+6x^2-9x=0$$

Note that this is the same as 
$$
x(36x^2+6x-9)=0
$$

So $0$ is a solution, and also the values for which $$36x^2+6x-9=0$$ are solutions. You can find the latter with the quadratic formula.

Comment: How do you know 0 is a solution?

Comment: One could say "staring at the equation for a while", or equivalently noting that the left hand side (of the equation I rewrote) is a polynomial with no constant term (and thus, 0 is one of its roots).

Comment: @MunizaSiddiqui  The product $ab = 0$ if and only if $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.  Here $a = x$ and $b = 36x^2 + 6x - 9$.